# Best way to have an area in an ASP.NET MVC4 application but disable routing to that area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an area in my ASP.NET MVC4 application. But that area is still under construction. When I ship the app, I'd like any routing to that area disabled. What is the best way to prevent the default convention picking up the request and redirecting to that area.

For example, say the area name is "NewFeature", I'd not like any requests to /someuri/NewFeature to be honored.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no routes to this area clients will never be able to call/utilize it. So what's the point of shipping it? But if you want to do it you could always comment the routing definition in the corresponding AreaRegistration file.

Comment: I want to do it just to support parallel feature development. I think when I added an area, ASP.NET automatically adds a default route in AreaRegistration.cs file. I just had to comment that out and it works as expected. Now, I can register that default route based on a configuration setting - development versus production. thanks!